# How to parse the attribute value of a <a> tag in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a html page for a database for universities and colleges in US. The code I wrote does fetches the names of the universities but I am unable to to fetch their respective url address.

```
public function fetch_universities()
{
    $url = "http://www.utexas.edu/world/univ/alpha/";   
    $dom = new DOMDocument();  
    $html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);  
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;   
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');   
    $tr = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    $td =  $tr->item(7)->getElementsByTagName('td');  
    $rows =  $td->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('li');

    $count = 0;
    foreach ($rows as $row)   
    {   
        $count++;
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('a');
        echo "$count:".$cols->item(0)->nodeValue. "\n";  
    }   
}
```

This is my code that I have currently.

Please tell me how to fetch the attribute values as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a reference to an element, you just have to use [`getAttribute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php), so probably:

```
echo "$count:".$cols->item(0)->getAttribute('href') . "\n";
```